# What does this phrase mean: 请回复我结果?

Tags: translation

What does this phrase mean:

> 请回复我结果

Comment: https://translate.google.com/

Comment: 谢谢，但是我不明白为啥他们用 “我结果”这句话

Answer (score 1, accepted):

看起来提问者懂中文，那我就先中文答吧：这是在香港，台湾地区口语用的比较多的间接宾语后置用法，普通话一般没有这样的用法

this kind of usage is common in Cantonese, but not in mandarin(common usage in the  Mainkind China ). “请回复我结果” is the same as "请把结果告诉我", that is "please tell me the result" in English. I think it is a kind of postposition of indirect object in cantonese, Putonghua doesn't have this

Comment: 谢谢你的帮助。我跟温州人沟通收到这样的邮件。有的时候真糊涂。温州不是香港，也不是台湾，但是中国南方。

Comment: @roman117 随着粤语地区和普通话地区人们的交流越来越多，这种用法被非粤语作为母语的人使用也比较常见了

this is a cross-over of cantonese and mandarin. for now, some of us may use them directly and ignore the grammar rule, cuz most listener can understand it